# Modify an element in forEach doubles the entries

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm currently setting up this js exercise [here](https://exercism.org/tracks/javascript/exercises/high-score-board) however it seems it's not working corretcly as I got the duplication of all the entries, I cannot understand why.

Here's the code:

```
export function updateScore(scoreBoard, player, points) {
  scoreBoard[player] = scoreBoard[player] + points;
  return scoreBoard;
}

export function applyMondayBonus(scoreBoard) {
  Object.keys(scoreBoard).forEach((element) =>{
  updateScore(scoreBoard,element,scoreBoard[element] + 100)
  } );
  return scoreBoard;
}
```

Once I run the code: I got this output

```
Object {
-   "Amil Pastorius": 445,
-   "Jesse Johnson": 222,
-   "Min-seo Shin": 119,
+   "Amil Pastorius": 790,
+   "Jesse Johnson": 344,
+   "Min-seo Shin": 138,
  }
```

Instead of this

```
{
      'Amil Pastorius': 445,
      'Min-seo Shin': 119,
      'Jesse Johnson': 222,
    };
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: My bad, that was a logical error as @Ivar said, I'm passing scoreBoard[element] + 100 as a parameter, then again use scoreBoard[element] in scoreBoard[player] + points.

Comment: Why not share the Object input you're using (`scoreBoard`)?

Comment: The output you're seeing isn't a valid javascript object (they can't have repeated keys). Can you clarify where you're seeing this (where are the `+` and `-` symbols before the keys coming from)?

Comment: Looks like some **git diff** to me :)

Comment: Added the source: it's an exercise in exercism.org who show you as a diff the expected ones.

Comment: You are using the old score twice. First you pass `scoreBoard[element] + 100` as a parameter, then you again use `scoreBoard[element]` in `scoreBoard[player] + points`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could very simply write:

```js
export function applyMondayBonus(scoreBoard = {}){
   Object.keys(scoreBoard).forEach(player => {
      scoreBoard[player] += 100
   })
   return scoreBoard
}
```

My advice would be to just write the function logic directly in the `forEach` loop. For such small and direct logic, a separate function could be a hassle.